# Identify Folders in Sub-Folder

Tags: julia

I have a working directory with the following content

```
readdir()

6-element Vector{String}:
 "Manifest.toml"
 "Project.toml"
 "Report"
 "main.jl"
 "src"
 "test.jl"
```

I can identify folders here:

```
filter(isdir, readdir())

2-element Vector{String}:
 "Report"
 "src"
```

And I can show the content of the sub-folder `Report`:

```
readdir("Report/")

3-element Vector{String}:
 "jl_ACKKIu"
 "jl_zfa8Ys"
 "test.pdf"
```

So, why can I not identify folders in the sub-folder?

```
filter(isdir, readdir("Report/"))

String[]
```

Comment: That's a bit surprising - for me it works with some sub-folders but not others. What does seem to do the trick is using `readdir("Report"; join = true)` so that the full path of the files and subfolders in the directory are returned from `readdir`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`readdir`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.readdir) contains paths relative to the input directory and [`isdir`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.isdir) then interprets these paths as relative to the current working directory (see [`pwd`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.pwd)).

Since Julia 1.4 you can pass `join=true` as a keyword argument to `readdir`, such that the returned paths are joined with the input path:

```
shell> tree .
.
├── DirectoryB
│   ├── DirectoryC
│   └── FileB
└── FileA

2 directories, 2 files

julia> readdir("DirectoryB")
2-element Vector{String}:
 "DirectoryC"
 "FileB"

julia> readdir("DirectoryB"; join=true)
2-element Vector{String}:
 "DirectoryB/DirectoryC"
 "DirectoryB/FileB"

julia> filter(isdir, ans)
1-element Vector{String}:
 "DirectoryB/DirectoryC"
```